# Run a command using Node.js on an EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a command on my EC2 instance using the `ssh2` node package:

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2')
const fs = require('fs')

const CONFIG = {
  hostname: '...',
  port: 22,
  username: 'ubuntu',
  privateKeyPath: './EC2.pem',
  passphrase: null,
}

const COMMANDS = ['ls']

function executeRemoteCommands() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const outputs = []
    const client = new Client()

    client
      .on('ready', () => {
        let remaining = COMMANDS.length
        for (const cmd of COMMANDS) {
          client.exec(cmd, (err, stream) => {
            if (err) reject(err)

            stream
              .on('close', (code, signal) => {
                remaining--
                if (remaining === 0) {
                  client.end()
                  resolve(outputs)
                }
              })
              .on('data', (data) => {
                outputs.push(data.toString())
              })
              .stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                reject(data.toString())
              })
          })
        }
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
      .connect({
        host: CONFIG.hostname,
        port: CONFIG.port,
        username: CONFIG.username,
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync(CONFIG.privateKeyPath),
        passphrase: CONFIG.passphrase,
      })
  })
}

executeRemoteCommands().then((outputs) => {
  console.log(outputs)
})
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:865
        const err = new Error('All configured authentication methods failed');
                    ^

Error: All configured authentication methods failed
    at doNextAuth (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:865:21)
    at tryNextAuth (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:1082:7)
    at USERAUTH_FAILURE (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:430:11)
    at 51 (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\handlers.misc.js:408:16)
    at Protocol.onPayload (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:2052:10)
    at AESGCMDecipherNative.decrypt (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\crypto.js:987:26)   
    at Protocol.parsePacket [as _parse] (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:2021:25)
    at Protocol.parse (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:306:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (function\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:775:21)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28) {
  level: 'client-authentication'
}
```

- The EC2.pem key is valid, I've been using it for a long time.
- The path is correct, otherwise I would get an `ENOENT` error.
- The instance has port 22 open.
- For username I tried `ubuntu@<the ip address>`, `root`, doesn't work.
- I don't know what kind of passphrase I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be confused about what username/passphrase to use, which sounds like you haven't even connected over a regular `ssh` command to this instance yet. Is that the case? You should really get a basic `ssh` command working first before trying to automate everting. The ssh command's verbose output would also give more information about any login issues.

Comment: I suspect the problem might be with permissions. On my macbook I can SSH to the server (after setting perms to 400), but on windows I can't SSH at all. I tried all solutions for ssh permissions under windows, nothing worked so far.

Comment: What error do you get when running the ssh command in windows? And also, whatever username/passphrase you use on the mac would also be the same thing you would use here.

Comment: I'm using a key file, the same that works on my laptop. I get `Permission denied (publickey)` on windows. It's the exact same command and key file.